# How to change product name after add to cart magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2.2

How to change the name of the product, when adding a product to the cart using observer in Magento 2
I use the following code:

```
$item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
$item->setName('helllloo');
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

The price is well updated but not the name.
Also, how can i change the text of the success message?

Answer (score 0):

You must change the product name, not the item . Please try this :

```
$item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
        $item->getProduct()->setName('helllloo');
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```